# how to show directional points with poly line in google map api? (Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined)

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to show directional points with poly line in google maps API but it creates a error. Anybody help to solve this problem.

> Error: polyline-map.php:50 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
>       at polyline-map.php:50

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:400px; width:400px"></div>   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>
    var map;
    var polyline;
    var markers = [   new google.maps.LatLng(17.43495, 78.50898333),
        new google.maps.LatLng(17.43495, 78.50898333),
        new google.maps.LatLng(17.43938333, 78.52168333),
        new google.maps.LatLng(17.43708333, 78.52925),
        new google.maps.LatLng(17.4366, 78.53336667)
        ];
    function init() {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        var moptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.43938333, 78.52168333),
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), moptions);
        var iconsetngs = {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW
        };
        var polylineoptns = {
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 3,
            map: map,
            icons: [{
                repeat: '70px', //CHANGE THIS VALUE TO CHANGE THE DISTANCE BETWEEN ARROWS
                icon: iconsetngs,
                offset: '100%'}]
        };
        polyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polylineoptns);
        var z = 0;
        var path = [];
        path[z] = polyline.getPath();
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) //LOOP TO DISPLAY THE MARKERS
        {
            var pos = markers[i];
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map
            });
            path[z].push(marker.getPosition()); //PUSH THE NEWLY CREATED MARKER'S POSITION TO THE PATH ARRAY
        }
    }
    window.onload = init;

</script>       
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&callback=init">
</script>
```

Comment: What is line 50?

Comment: new google.maps.LatLng(17.43495, 78.50898333)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the Google Maps Javascript API v3 asynchronously (`async defer` `&callback=init`), you can't use any of the `google.maps` namespace until it has loaded (when the callback function runs).

If you want to define the coordinates for your polyline outside of the `init` function, use [`LatLngLiteral`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/coordinates#LatLngLiteral) anonymous objects:

Change:

```
var markers = [   new google.maps.LatLng(17.43495, 78.50898333),
    new google.maps.LatLng(17.43495, 78.50898333),
    new google.maps.LatLng(17.43938333, 78.52168333),
    new google.maps.LatLng(17.43708333, 78.52925),
    new google.maps.LatLng(17.4366, 78.53336667)
    ];
```

To:

```
var markers = [   {lat:17.43495,lng: 78.50898333},
    {lat:17.43495,lng: 78.50898333},
    {lat:17.43938333,lng: 78.52168333},
    {lat:17.43708333,lng: 78.52925},
    {lat:17.4366,lng: 78.53336667}
    ];
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wyudenkm/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var map;
  var polyline;
  var markers = [   {lat:17.43495,lng: 78.50898333},
        {lat:17.43495,lng: 78.50898333},
        {lat:17.43938333,lng: 78.52168333},
        {lat:17.43708333,lng: 78.52925},
        {lat:17.4366,lng: 78.53336667}
        ];

  function init() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var moptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.43938333, 78.52168333),
      zoom: 14,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), moptions);
    var iconsetngs = {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW
    };
    var polylineoptns = {
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      map: map,
      icons: [{
        repeat: '70px', //CHANGE THIS VALUE TO CHANGE THE DISTANCE BETWEEN ARROWS
        icon: iconsetngs,
        offset: '100%'
      }]
    };
    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polylineoptns);
    var z = 0;
    var path = [];
    path[z] = polyline.getPath();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) //LOOP TO DISPLAY THE MARKERS
    {
      var pos = markers[i];
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map
      });
      path[z].push(marker.getPosition()); //PUSH THE NEWLY CREATED MARKER'S POSITION TO THE PATH ARRAY
    }
  }
  window.onload = init;
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=init">
</script>
```